# If I convert my LibGDX game to an exe, is it legal?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a LibGDX jar file, and I want to have it as an EXE. Would that be legal? (Using launch4j)

Also, how do I obfuscate a LibGDX game?

Comment: Never get legal advice from the web. Read the licenses attached to LibGDX.

Comment: And obfuscation is a seperate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why wouldn't it? As stated on BadLogicGaming's Official Website:

> The license basically states you can do with the source whatever you want, copy it, modify it, include it in open and closed source projects without getting infected by the license itself.

You can do whatever you want with what you made. Just make sure you comply to these 3 lines **if you ever modify the source code if LibGDX**:

> - include the license file in your project
> - retain all copyright notices of my (modified) source files
> - if you chose to contribute your contribution will the Apache 2.0 licensed to

Source: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=777

As of your second question, here is a site that lists Java obfuscators:

http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators

ProGuard seems like the best choice.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I just want to distribute my game in exe format, nothing else. I won't touch the source, I have no experience in doing all that stuff anyway.

Comment: @user49592 Then there is absolutely no problem distributing your game as an .exe. You could even sell it!

Comment: Nice to know! Thanks a lot :) Being a 13 year old coder isn't a problem, but being a 13 year old and understand this legal stuff is a bit hard haha :)